# How we can read unstructured xml file in pyspark

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing, pyspark

```
<editors>
    <p poid="1232" class="odo">
        <person id="1232">Rob Jhon</person>
        <br /> **this text need to be read**
        <br />
        <title>Sto items:</title> **"this text need to be read"**
        <br />
        <title>Recent items:</title> **this text need to be read**

    </p>
</editors>
```

As you see in my dataset there are some string areas which are not tagged.
How can i read this xml properly in pyspark to see this string field as a column as well.

Comment: Is this a one-time task you need to perform, or will the XML look slightly different in future examples?

Comment: You will probably need [`Element.tail`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) at some point.

Comment: Its gonna be same type in the future. I need to give tag without tag text. That all what i need.

Answer (score 0):

If xml is a file called "data.xml", you could start with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print(root[0][1].tail)
```

This works for me.

[image: Works for me]